# What is the difference between "int x" and "(int)x"?

Tags: c++

I wanted to know the difference in C++ of the following examples. Why example two is not applicable?

First example:

```
void ReceiveServerConnect(BYTE* ReceiveBuffer) 
{
    LPPRECEIVE_SERVER_ADDRESS Data = (LPPRECEIVE_SERVER_ADDRESS) ReceiveBuffer;
}
```

Second example:

```
void ReceiveServerConnect(BYTE* ReceiveBuffer) 
{
    LPPRECEIVE_SERVER_ADDRESS Data = LPPRECEIVE_SERVER_ADDRESS ReceiveBuffer;
}
```

Comment: One is valid C++, and the other won't compile?

Comment: Because such are the rules of the language?

Comment: `(LPPRECEIVE_SERVER_ADDRESS)` is a "C" style cast and converts a pointer to a BYTE to a pointer to a struct (and "C" style casts should not be used anymore), second isn't valid C++.  It should be ` LPPRECEIVE_SERVER_ADDRESS Data = static_cast<LPPRECEIVE_SERVER_ADDRESS>(ReceiveBuffer);`. See : [explicit-type-conversion-casting-and-static-cast](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/explicit-type-conversion-casting-and-static-cast/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example, with the parentheses, is doing a cast from one type to another.  It's an old-style C cast which is a very blunt instrument.  For C++ you should prefer one of the new styles:

```
LPPRECEIVE_SERVER_ADDRESS Data = static_cast<LPPRECEIVE_SERVER_ADDRESS>(ReceiveBuffer);
```

The second example is simply bad syntax and should be rejected by the compiler with an error.  Without the parentheses it looks like you're trying to declare a variable in the middle of an expression.

That's just the syntax that C++ has adopted, best to just accept it and not try to make much sense of it.